# Figures referencing problem

Tags: cross-referencing

I am having a problem with referencing figure with elsevier template when I reference an image I got only the number but not figure 1 for example .
Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items
\modulolinenumbers[5]


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
 c
 c
 the \ref{fig:example} blabla
 c
 c
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
 \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{name of the figure}
 \caption{the name of the figure}
 \label{fig:example}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

I got only  the 1 blabla

Normally I should get the figure 1 blabla

Comment: Your example is not compilable since the image file is not available, but usually `1` is the correct output. If you want `figure 1`, use `cleveref` and `\cref`. And `hyperref` should be loaded at the end of the preamble, not right at its start

Comment: Please take into account that this article might be rejected with `figure 1` if being submitted to `Elsevier`

Comment: Adding `.gif` to the list of possible extensions doesn't make GIF files suitable for insertion, as `pdftex` doesn't support them.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of using `\includegraphics` with the `scale=...` option, it's usually more straightforward to employ the option`width=0.8\textwidth` (or some other, suitable fraction of `\textwidth`).

Answer (score 4):

By default, the output of `\ref` does not yield `figure` for a figure counter label. This can be improved with `cleveref` and `\cref` or a redefinition of `\p@figure`, for example.

The solutions below show each usage independently:

```
\documentclass[review,demo]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}


\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items
\modulolinenumbers[5]


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
 the \ref{fig:example} or \cref{fig:example} blabla
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{name of the figure}
   \caption{the name of the figure}
   \label{fig:example}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Solution with `\p@figure` being changed:

```
\documentclass[review,demo]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@figure}{\lowercase{\figurename}\ }
\makeatother


\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items
\modulolinenumbers[5]


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
 the \ref{fig:example} blabla
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{name of the figure}
   \caption{the name of the figure}
   \label{fig:example}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest using `cleveref` as being the cleaner solution

Comment: Thanks it works now I have seen some elsevier papers they use fig.1 not figure 1 how can I change it to fig.1

Comment: @twimo: Remove the `noabbrev` option from the loading of `cleveref`. `\cref` will show `fig.` then and `\Cref` will provide `Fig.`

Comment: Thanks a lot christian you are a saver  and one last thing why will they reject a paper for using figure 1 ?

Comment: @twimo: Perhaps Elsevier has certain typesetting/publishing guidelines to which each author has to comply to. This depends on the type of journal etc. Other publishers have other typographic/publishing rules.

Comment: @twimo: If my solution fits your needs, consider to accept it please

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, you are right about the guidelines, we have to follow them, a small detail can affect the whole work